# Automating (Angular?) website page scraping/analysis workflow with MV3 Chrome Extension

Tags: angular, dom, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

## **MY CONTEXT:**

I'm on this personal project to automate a relatively complex and inter-related workflow across two different and independent "3rd party service" websites by developing a Chrome extension under MV3; this includes site interaction, along with Dropbox and GoogleSheets read & write interactions.

In a simplified nutshell, my Chrome MV3 extension:

1. monitors a personal Dropbox folder;
2. triggers new requests to the FIRST website based on new detected files in Dropbox;
3. monitors and detects changes in those requests in the FIRST website;
4. triggers related new requests and tracks corresponding changes across the SECOND website until full completion;

My extension maintains a log  of all these interactions and current request status in a Google Sheet.

In both websites, monitoring changes in the requests requires navigating to a specific "history" area -with potentially multiple pages-, "scraping" information on a per-request basis, comparing and updating this new information with the previous information as maintained in my Google Sheets.

I first designed the "history scraping and analysis" work by having the Chrome browser navigate and flick through the history pages; I got this working, although I did not like the approach as I felt the visual "flicking" of the multiple pages did not provide an optimal user experience.

So, in order to provide a smoother user experience I decided to visually hide the "history scraping and analysis" work from the user by:

1. "fetching" (with new XMLHttpRequest()) each of the history pages into a "DOM" variable in the background
2. performing the DOM scraping from the variable that contains the DOM
3. just informing the user what was going on with messages (like "analysing requests on page 1", "analysing requests on page 2", etc...)

This is working PERFECTLY on my FIRST website.

## **MY PROBLEM:**

The SECOND website is surely designed differently.

From my research, I think the second website might be built with Angular, but I do not have any certainty or knowledge of that.

PLEASE NOTE: I cannot provide direct access to the site as it is user/password protected, so I'm attaching relevant screenshots

When I have Chrome physically navigate to the "history area" and flick through the page(s), they do render "fully" in the browser;

Specifically, the information I need to scrap seems to be under a custom  tag; in any case, these contents are visible through "Developer Tools" console, and accessible with standard "document.getElement(s).*" commands in my scripts so I can scrape all the information I need.

[sample site screenshot with DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7p7N.jpg)

## **HOWEVER:**

When I "fetch" the website pages(s) in my script into a variable (using new XMLHttpRequest()), and although the DOM document does actually get stored in the variable, the DOM contents show the  tag -where I believe all the history contents should be- as empty, so I cannot scrape anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3jc3.jpg)

I then also realised that even when I physically navigate in the Chrome browser to the actual history page (as described in the details of my problem), what I see in the PAGE SOURCE -available through  View->Developer->View Source does NOT show any contents inside the custom  tag, which is empty

So I understand there seems to be a difference between what the browser displays and the actual page source (which it's also what is retrieved in the "fetch" script action), but I do not know how to access the actual content that the browser displays.

## **MY QUESTIONS:**:

1. Is there anything I can do to force those "history" contents included in the "fetch" call and stored in my script variable?
2. Do I need to / can I trigger any of those scripts in the page to feed them into the variable?  If so, can you indicate which script(s)?
3. Or is it my only resort to physically "flick" through the pages in the Chrome browser as I initially did?

I'm just a javascript newbie, coming up from a mediocre python developer, so please excuse my ignorance

Comment: No, this approach won't work with js-based sites. The solution is to run sites inside an iframe inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). Your content script should have [all_frames](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames) to run inside the iframe. You might also need to [strip the DENY header](/a/69177790).

Answer (score 0):

first of all, thanks to wOxxOm for your suggestion; after some lengthy time of self-learning and trial-error, I came up with an approach which, if not 100%  what I wanted, it is good enough for my purposes. While it  is not technically based on wOxxOm's suggestion ("offscreen document"), as I did not see how to apply it to my problem, I used the 'conceptual idea' itself of an 'offscreen document'. So, for anybody coming here with a similar problem, what worked for me was:

1. in my content script: I open a second (non-active) tab where the navigation to the page that needs to be scraped takes place, using chrome.tabs.create({url: targetURL, active: false}). This is what I would call a "background" or "secondary" tab, hence the related idea of an "offscreen document"
2. Although the tab is physically visible (a new tab opens in the same browser window), it does not take the user away from the active tab, so it is very close to something happening elsewhere from where the user is.
3. in my background script: my chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener detects when any of those secondary tab completes (I use a regex mapper in the URL, since any of those detail pages follow a similar structured url), and then runs  the scraping on that secondary tab/page  using chrome.scripting.executeScript on that tabId. The results of the scraping are stored in local storage. I also saw this idea of chrome.scripting.executeScript in another answer from wOxxOm.
4. back in my content script, I retrieve the scraped contents from local storage and then close the "secondary" tab.

Quite clunky, but it works seamlessly for my purposes even when I need to scrape a series of 40+ items. All my javascript is clunky, anyways, as I have not yet learned to embrace the nature of the language yet and I find myself fighting against it instead to do things as I would expect them to happen.
I give all credit to the pointers on this direction to wOxxOm, thanks again!